# Woocommerce is_purchasable hook for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the below code to make all products on woocommerce not purchasable unless the user is signed in.

```
function et_remove_atc(){
    
        
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
    
        return false;
    
    }else{
        
        return true;
        
    }
    
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'et_remove_atc' );
```

This only works for simple products and not variable products. I've tried to add the below additional filter, but this doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'et_remove_atc', 10, 2 );
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the right hook for variable products and its variations. Note that the add to cart button on variable products will stay grayed (disabled) for guests. If it is not the case, it can be due to a plugin, your theme customizations or some other customizations made by you.

The correct code to be used is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'avoid_guest_purchases' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'avoid_guest_purchases' );
function avoid_guest_purchases( $is_purchasable ){
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        return false;
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To remove variable add to cart button (on single product pages) for guests, use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_variable_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function remove_variable_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for that - i'll update with the attached. In terms of the Add To Cart button being disabled - would there be a way to remove it, so the functionality is the same as the simple products (the above removes the add to cart button completely on simple products - on the single product page anyway - on archive pages it swaps it for a 'read more button' which fine)

Comment: @EthanThomas I have added some more code to remove add to cart button on variable products…

Comment: Doesn't appear to remove the ATC button LoicTheAztec. Ideally what i'm looking to achieve is the entire cart form is removed (like it is on a simple product page) So the drop-down, qty selector and at too cart button is not there. For clarity, the reason for this is, i'm inserting another piece of text and login buttons in it's place when a user is not logged in, so it's confusing to have this displayed in addition to the add to cart button

Comment: @EthanThomas Maybe because there are some customizations making trouble made by your theme, a plugin or yourself. My answer code works just fine since WooCommerce 3 (tested on last WooCommerce version under storefront theme).

Comment: No problem, i'll look into this with the theme dev. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's Default woocommerce setting. you allow guest customer or not.

Uncheck checkbox allow customer to place order without account

Check this screenshot: **https://prnt.sc/11fj0kc**